# MacBook unibody 2010 will not charge reliably

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, magsafe

I have a 2010 MacBook unibody (the white one, not the Pro) and I have been having all sorts of trouble with it. While I have most of the other problems figured out, there is one that keep persisting and I've tried everything I can think of (or find) to fix it:

- the MacBook will not charge reliably.

It will charge for about a week, then it quits working and dies and I can't use it for a few days. Everything I know/tried is listed below.

**What I Know:**

- the MagSafe charger seems to work for a few days, then stop working for a few days
- it only seems to stop working when my MacBook's battery dips below 30%
- once it stops working, I can not get it to work again unless I unplug it from the wall and the MacBook and let it sit for over 24 hours
- the MagSafe charger is *immaculate*. No dirt anywhere on the charger or the port
- the MacBook discharges even when the adapter is connected
- the light on the charger is off when it does not work (even when connected)
- all pins are making proper contact with the MacBook
- there is current going through the cable and into the MacBook.

**What I Have Tried:**

- cleaning the charger and port
- using different wall adapters
- using different outlets
- resetting the SMC and the NVRAM
- warming up the charger.

Unfortunately I don't have access to another first generation MagSafe MacBook or MagSafe charger so I have not been able to find out which part is broken: the MacBook or the charger.

Taking it to the Apple Store is not something I am willing to do, so I'd prefer a solution that does not involve me leaving my house.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you've tried everything... If there is enough power left to boot you could go to the Apple Menu > About this Mac > System Report > Power > AC Charger Information and have a look if it recognises the charger, and check the battery health.

If this isn't an option because the battery is flat, or health is good and the charger isn't recognised. Then sadly you are going to have to leave the house.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just got it to start charging again and it does recognize the charger as well as the wattage, and it reports the battery health as "normal". I figure its probably time to buy a new charger :/

Comment: Who down votes a answer like this?

Comment: I thought it was a solid answer (Thanks btw). I'd upvote it but my account is too new.

Comment: People are strange.